# Getting accountEnabled for a user in Microsoft Azure AD

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I'm using REST API towards Microsoft Graph and making a `PATCH` request to set `accountEnabled` to `false`. This works fine, the account becomes suspended and I can't login with it.

However, when I `GET` from `/v1.0/users/{{id}` I do not get the `accountEnabled` status back. Hence, I cannot know if the user account is disabled without saving its state in some local database (which I prefer not to).

How can I retrieve the accountEnabled state for a user?

Comment: Have you tried explicitly selecting it with `$select=accountEnabled`. You would of course have to specify all the field names you want to select, comma-separated.

Comment: oh, it was that easy! Many thanks for pointing that out. Didn't knew I could use selectors for the call.

Comment: Cool, I'll add an answer :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `$select` to specify additional fields you want to return. By default the users endpoint returns a limited set.

So for example:

```
/v1.0/users?$select=id,accountEnabled
```

You have to specify every field that you want it to return in comma-separated form.

Usage instructions for `$select` and other parameters can be found here: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/query_parameters#select-parameter

Comment: What permissions should I set for the Application / API ? The App has permissions 
`User.ReadWrite.All` and `UserAuthenticationMethod.ReadWrite.All` but still the API returns "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation". However creation and update of users work fine with the API...

Comment: User.ReadWrite.All is definitely enough. Have you inspected the access token you send to MS Graph? You can decode it at e.g. https://jwt.ms and see if the needed permission is there.